# Simple dropdown select option | display dependent on selected options

Tags: css

Below I paste code for simple dropdown with some options.

Choose a module:

```
<select name="modules" id="module-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="module1">Module1</option>
    <option value="module2">Module2</option>
    <option value="module3">Module3</option>
    <option value="module4">Module4</option>
    <option value="module5">Module5</option>
    <option value="module6">Module6</option>
</select>

<br /><br /><br />
<!-- options for module 1 --->
<label for="server-select">Choose a server:</label>

<select name="servers" id="server-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="server1">Server1</option>
    <option value="server2">Server2</option>
    <option value="server3">Server3</option>
    <option value="server4">Server4</option>
    <option value="server5">Server5</option>
    <option value="server6">Server6</option>
</select>

<br /><br /><br />
<!-- options for module 2 --->
<label for="server-select">Choose a server:</label>

<select name="servers" id="server-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="server1">Server1</option>
    <option value="server2">Server2</option>
    <option value="server3">Server3</option>
    <option value="server4">Server4</option>
    <option value="server5">Server5</option>
    <option value="server6">Server6</option>
</select>

<!-- etc -->

<style>
label,
footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

select {
    font-size: .9rem;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}

footer {
    font-size: .8rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}

.output {
    background: center/cover no-repeat url('/media/cc0-images/hamster.jpg');
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

I need display options for module 1, if customer select from first dropdown module1
I need display options for module 2, if customer select module2  from first dropdown

Can anyone help me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var el = document.getElementById("module-select");
el.addEventListener("change", choosemodule, false);

function choosemodule() {
  var m = document.getElementsByClassName('h');
  for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    m[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  var n = document.getElementById("module-select").selectedIndex;
  if (n > 0) {
    document.getElementById('s' + n).style.display = 'block';
  }

}
```

```css
label,
footer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

select {
  font-size: .9rem;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

footer {
  font-size: .8rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}

.output {
  background: center/cover no-repeat url('/media/cc0-images/hamster.jpg');
  position: relative;
}

.h {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="modules" id="module-select">
  <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
  <option value="module1">Module1</option>
  <option value="module2">Module2</option>
  <option value="module3">Module3</option>
  <option value="module4">Module4</option>
  <option value="module5">Module5</option>
  <option value="module6">Module6</option>
</select>

<br /><br /><br />
<div id="s1" class="h">
  <!-- options for module 1 --->
  <label for="server-select">Choose a server 1:</label>

  <select name="servers">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="server1">Server1</option>
    <option value="server2">Server2</option>
    <option value="server3">Server3</option>
    <option value="server4">Server4</option>
    <option value="server5">Server5</option>
    <option value="server6">Server6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<!-- options for module 2 --->
<div id="s2" class="h">
  <label for="server-select">Choose a server 2:</label>

  <select name="servers">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="server1">Server1</option>
    <option value="server2">Server2</option>
    <option value="server3">Server3</option>
    <option value="server4">Server4</option>
    <option value="server5">Server5</option>
    <option value="server6">Server6</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="s3" class="h">s3</div>
<div id="s4" class="h">s4</div>
<div id="s5" class="h">s5</div>
<div id="s6" class="h">s6</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

Comment: @Guys, thank for this help. Working perfect. Can I ask with one more thing ?  Do you have any solution, if I select example module1 and server 1 then display extra text ? and when I select module1 and server2 then also under dropdowns display other custom text assigned to selected option ?

Comment: You can change "id=s1, id=s2 ..." to any where you want to display.